# JLabel is re-rendered on JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple app which is basically a splash screen to start some programs. The whole app is just a single JFrame with 4 elements:

- Background image
- Logo image
- ProgressBar
- Text message to print current state.

I've create this class

```java
package com.example;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("");
    private final JProgressBar jProgressBar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);

    private String message;
    private int dots = 0;

    public SplashScreen() {

        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(SplashScreen.class.getResource("/favicon.png")));

        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(600, 350);
        this.setSize(dimension);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);

        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);


        jProgressBar.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 50));
        jProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        jProgressBar.setBorderPainted(false);
        jProgressBar.setValue(0);
        jProgressBar.setBounds(50, 270, 500, 30);
        jProgressBar.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        jProgressBar.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI() {
            protected Color getSelectionBackground() { return new Color(0x66,0x10,0xf2); }
            protected Color getSelectionForeground() { return new Color(0x6f,0x42,0xc1); }
        });
        contentPane.add(jProgressBar);


        jLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        jLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        jLabel.setBounds(50, 200, 500, 30);
        jLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        jLabel.setLabelFor(jProgressBar);
        contentPane.add(jLabel);

        JImage logo = new JImage("images/logo.png");
        logo.setBounds(141,50,318, 118);
        contentPane.add(logo);

        JImage background = new JImage("images/background.jpg");
        background.setSize(dimension);
        background.setLocation(0, 0);
        contentPane.add(background);

        contentPane.validate();

        java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dots = (dots + 1) % 4;
                jLabel.setText(getMessage());
                contentPane.validate();
            }
        }, 0, 300);

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        jLabel.setText(getMessage());
        contentPane.validate();
    }
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        jProgressBar.setValue(progress);
        contentPane.validate();
    }
    private String getMessage() {
        return this.message + new String(new char[this.dots]).replace("\0", ".");
    }

    public static class JImage extends JLabel {
        private ImageIcon image;

        public JImage(String path){
            super();
            setIcon(path);
        }
        public void setIcon(String path) {
            image = load(path);
            super.setIcon(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
            super.setIcon(icon);
            if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
                image = ((ImageIcon) icon);
            else
                image = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(image == null ? null : image.getImage(), 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        }

        private ImageIcon load(String path) {
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
                image = ImageIO.read(stream);
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("E/ Failed to load image");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new ImageIcon(image);
        }
    }
}
```

My main class just makes the frame visible and launches a list of programs sequentially in separate cmd windows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    SplashScreen window = new SplashScreen();
    window.setVisible(true);

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int percent = 0;

    for (State state: cycle) {
        window.setMessage(state.message);
        runtime.exec(start(state.title, state.path, state.command));
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(state.timeout);
        percent += state.progress;
        window.setProgress(percent);
    }
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2000);
    System.exit(0);
}

private static String start(String title, String path, String command){
    return String.format("cmd /c start \"%s\" /d \"%s\" /min cmd.exe /k \"%s\"", title, path, command);
}
```

Some how the splash screen renders the JLabel in the correct spot and re-render it on the JProgressBar.

I tried moving the ProgressBar yet the text follows it. I tried removing the Label itself now the ProgressBar starts re-rendering on itself.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Several issues are immediately visible: If you override a painting method, you should call the super's method in your override to allow the component to do housekeeping painting -- you don't do this. You should almost never paint directly in a paint method, but rather should paint in a JPanel's paintComponent method (and call super.paintComponent(g) in the override). If you're overriding a JLabel, don't override its paint or paintComponent. Perhaps override paintIcon. Never use a java.util.Timer for a Swing project as this isn't thread-safe. use a javax.swing.Timer.

Comment: You also use null layout and set bounds,... not good

Comment: Oh, and this, `new Color(255, 255, 255, 50)` is valid Java but not well used by the Swing library. It does not work well with semi-opaque components.

Comment: Swing is also not thread safe. You should not be updating the UI or any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: `public static class JImage extends JLabel {` .... why?  `JLabel` already has icon support - this seems otherwise completely redudent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What did I do wrong ?

A lot of things (sorry).

Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe.  This is means that you can't run blocking or long running operations on the Event Dispatching Thread, it also means that you shouldn't update the UI or the any state the UI relies on from out side the Event Dispatching Thread context.

So, your loop in your `main` method and the use of `java.util.Timer` are violating the thread safety rule.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Using `null` layouts.  This might not seem like a big deal to you, but it will become a massive headache as you progress further.  Take the time to learn and understand the various layout options available to you.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

You're violating the painting process.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image == null ? null : image.getImage(), 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
 }
```

`paint` is a very complex method which does a lot of work, as a generally recommendation, you should avoid overriding `paint` and instead override `paintComponent`, but you must ensure that you either call `super.paintComponent` or re-implement the functionality that the method does.

`Graphics` is a shared context which is passed to each component during a paint process.  One of the jobs that the painting process does, is "clear" what was previously painted, this is why it's important to ensure that you're working within the painting process.

I would suggest looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

The `JImage` class doesn't really make sense. `JLabel` is already very good at rendering images.  If you wanted to make a simpler workflow (which you're not really doing), I might consider creating a factory method or utility class to create a `JLabel` with the configuration you want.

`jProgressBar.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 50));` - Swing components doesn't support alpha based colors, they are either fully opaque or fully transparent.

IMHO I'd be wary of doing something like `public JImage(String path){`.  I mean, what does `String path` actually mean?  Is it a file path on the local disk?  Is it a named resource? Is it something else.  Generally speaking, I would recommend using `File` and `URL` as it's clear what the source should be - just saying.

## So, what's the solution?

Make use of a `SwingWorker` to perform long running operations, this allows you to easily sync updates back the Event Dispatching Thread.  For repeating operations, use a Swing `Timer`, the "ticks" will be updated in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Instead of `JImage`, I'd just make use of `JLabel`, if required, making a factory method to create it with the configuration I needed.

With regards to the translucent background, that's a little more tricky, but I would be tempted to create a "translucent pane" and fake it.  I would then put the `JProgressBar` on this component.

For example...

[image]

Now, this might "look" complicated, but once you understand the basic principles, you can re-apply them to a lot of things you do.

First, there's a custom component which renders a background image, this extends from `JPanel` and is important, as some solutions might suggest using a `JLabel`, but `JLabel` is a complex component and calculates it's preferred size based on the `icon` and `text` and not the child components, this can easily lead in you into no end of issues.

We start with the background pane, onto this, we add the logo and the "progress content".  This is important, as we "cheat" a little here.  We add the logo and progress content in such away that they occupy the same space at the same time.  This allows the logo to appear centred on the screen and won't be affected by the other components.

On the "progress content", we add a "fill" component, this will force the progress bar and label to occupy the lower half of the view.  Then we add the progress bar and label (wrapped in yet another component) to the "progress content".

This will make the progress bar and label to appear in the lower half of the view.

This might "seem" complicated, but is a very flexible solution.  The size of the logo and font don't have adverse effects on each other, especially on systems where the font size might be larger then you original designed for.

Translucency is "faked" through another component, `TranslucentPane`.  You could create a custom `JProgressBar`, but this becomes more complicated as the paint process is more involved.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
                    frame.add(splashScreen);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    // I'm using a Timer here to simulate "work"
                    // Depending on your needs, you might need to use
                    // a SwingWorker instead.
                    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                        private int progress = 0;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            progress += 1;
                            if (progress >= 100) {
                                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            }
                            splashScreen.setProgress(progress);
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class SplashScreen extends JPanel {

        private final JLabel dotLabel = new JLabel("");
        private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);

        private String message = "";
        private int dots = 0;

        private Timer dotTimer;

        public SplashScreen() throws IOException {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            BackgroundPane backgroundPane = new BackgroundPane(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Mando01-50.png")));
            backgroundPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            backgroundPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(backgroundPane);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;

            JLabel logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Paw.png")));
            backgroundPane.add(logo, gbc);

            JPanel progressContentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            progressContentPane.setOpaque(false);

            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            backgroundPane.add(progressContentPane, gbc);

            // This just fills the top half of the view with an empty space
            // forcing the progress view down to the bottom half the
            // the screen.  This is done so we can "fake" the label position,
            // allowing to appear in the center of the screen and it will
            // be uneffected by the other elements ... tricky
            JPanel fillerPane = new JPanel();
            fillerPane.setOpaque(false);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;
            gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;

            JPanel progressPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            progressPane.setOpaque(false);

            progressContentPane.add(fillerPane, gbc);
            progressContentPane.add(progressPane, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            TranslucentPane progressBackgroundPane = new TranslucentPane();
            progressBackgroundPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            progressBackgroundPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            progressBackgroundPane.setAlpha(0.5f);

            progressBackgroundPane.add(progressBar);

            progressPane.add(progressBackgroundPane, gbc);
            progressPane.add(dotLabel, gbc);

            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setBorderPainted(false);
            progressBar.setValue(0);
            progressBar.setBounds(50, 270, 500, 30);
            progressBar.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            progressBar.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI() {
                protected Color getSelectionBackground() {
                    return new Color(0x66, 0x10, 0xf2);
                }

                protected Color getSelectionForeground() {
                    return new Color(0x6f, 0x42, 0xc1);
                }
            });

            dotTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dots = Math.max(1, (dots + 1) % 5);
                    dotLabel.setText(getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            dotTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            dotTimer.stop();
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
            dotLabel.setText(getMessage());
        }

        public void setProgress(int progress) {
            progressBar.setValue(progress);
        }

        private String getMessage() {
            return this.message + new String(new char[this.dots]).replace("\0", ".");
        }

        public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

            private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

            public BackgroundPane(BufferedImage backgroundImage) {
                this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
            }

            public BufferedImage getBackgroundImage() {
                return backgroundImage;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                BufferedImage backgroundImage = getBackgroundImage();
                if (backgroundImage == null) {
                    return super.getPreferredSize();
                }
                return new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                BufferedImage backgroundImage = getBackgroundImage();
                if (backgroundImage == null) {
                    return;
                }
                int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
            }
        }

        public class TranslucentPane extends JPanel {
            private float alpha = 1f;

            public TranslucentPane() {
                setOpaque(false);
            }

            public float getAlpha() {
                return alpha;
            }

            public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
                this.alpha = alpha;
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setColor(getBackground());
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(getAlpha()));
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, this is just an example, and there are number ways you might achieve the same effect(s), but this addresses the core issues you've presented.